# Time series forecasting for monthly utility data

Tags: pandas

I want to do some time series forecasting with a bunch of utilities data. The months and years are columns, and I'm wondering if there's a good way to take all these columns and make a 2000-01, 2000-02, ..., 2019-12 timestamp?

[image]

Comment: just to be clear, if the Year is 2000 or 2001 you want a new column that states '2000-2001' plus it wont be a timestamp, rather it will be an object dtype (string)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,3),
                  columns=['Jan','Feb','Mar']
                 ).assign(year=[2000,2001])

df.melt('year').assign(
    timestamp=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['year'].astype(str)+'-'+x['variable'])
)
```

Output:

```
   year variable     value  timestamp
0  2000      Jan  0.417022 2000-01-01
1  2001      Jan  0.302333 2001-01-01
2  2000      Feb  0.720324 2000-02-01
3  2001      Feb  0.146756 2001-02-01
4  2000      Mar  0.000114 2000-03-01
5  2001      Mar  0.092339 2001-03-01
```